# using nlsLM() and < length of 'dimnames' not equal to array extent> error

Tags: r, statistics, nls, non-linear-regression

The measurment points (`y_i`, `t_i`) are given (whereas in this minimal example the `y_i` is only 3-dim vector (originally from R^6) and `t_i` fixed time point. I had to (Not sure if the code, the way it is right now, expresses it) to apply the Gauss-Newton-method, so as to minimize the (double) sum of squared errors and find functions parameters `aj`, `cj` in the fitting system (in code  represented by the function `fitFunc()`).

As I kept getting an Inf small entries of the Jacobian matrix in my C++ implementation,  I googled for an alternative and stumbled across the `nls()` function in R (As I got the'singular gradient matrix' error when using `nls()`,I switched to `nlsLM()`)

Here is the minimal example (only with `N_0` and `N_r`, whereas the original system has 3 different sumExp-like functions, `N_0c` and `N_c` called in `fitfunc()`):

```
library(stats)
a_param<-c(0.0294, 0.296, 0.0959)
c_param<-c(0.0574, 0.2960142, 0.3199)
time<-c(0,36,48,60,72,96)
N_srt<-55827
                            
N_0 <- function(ti,cj) {N_srt*exp(-cj[1]*ti)}
                            
prod_a<-function (i, aj){ #input i>=2 
                         p<-1   
                         j<-1
                         while (j<=i-1){ 
                                       p <-p*aj[j] 
                                       j<-j+1
                                       }
                         p
                         }
                            
PaarProdukt<-function (j, i, cj){
                       p<-1
                       k<-1
                       while (k<=i){
                                   if (k!=j){ 
                                          p<-p*1/(cj[k]-cj[j])
                                          }
                                k<-k+1
                                }
                        p
                        }
                            
 sumExp<-function(i, cj, ti){ #input i>=2
                             s<-0
                             j<-1
                              
                             while (j <= i){
                                s<-s+exp(cj[j])*PaarProdukt(j,i,cj)
                                j<-j+1
                              }
                              s
                            } 
                            
                            
 N_r <- function(ti, i, cj, aj ){#i >2
                                P<-prod_a(i,aj) 
                                S<-sumExp(i,cj,ti)
                                2^(i-1)*N_srt*P*S 
                            }
                            
      #-------------------
      givendata<-c(55827,0,0,
                   18283,12197,0,
                   11678,15635,19550,
                   6722,8315,13609,
                   5104,3316,6282,
                   715,915,1418)

# as I was annoyed with the fact, that R repliates the vector "time"    3 times so as to match its size with the size of "givendata", I introduced 
zeitSpane<-c(0,0,0,36,36,36,48,48,48,60,60,60,72,72,72,96,96,96)
                            
  fitliste<-rep(0,18)
 
  fitFunc<-function(t,cj,aj){ #t muss be of length 18
  counter<-1
  
  while (counter <= 18){
    i <- counter %% 3
    if (i == 1){
      
      fitliste[counter]<-N_0(t[counter],cj)
      }else{
        if (i==0) {i<-3
        }else{i<-2}
        
      fitliste[counter]<-N_r(t[counter],i,cj,aj)+counter
      }
    counter<-counter+1
  }
  fitliste
}
df<- data.frame(givendata=givendata, t=zeitSpane )

nlsLM(givendata~fitFunc(t,cj,aj), data =df, start=list(t=zeitSpane,cj=c_param,aj=a_param))
```

I now got this

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("t", "cj", "aj")) :
> length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
> In addition: Warning message:In matrix(out$hessian, nrow =length(unlist(par))) :
> data length [9] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [24]

Q: Do you know how to fix this error? From where comes this 9 in the warning message?

Comment: This is not the way `nls(...)` works. `df` has to be a data.frame with your (x,y) pairs, so something like `df <- data.frame(givendata=givendata, t=time)`. Problem here is that `time` has only 6 elements and `givendata` has 18. Are these supposed to be replicates?? Then your objective function has to be something like `fitfunc(t,cj,aj)`. That is, it has to explicitly depend on the predictor variable (`t` in this case).

Comment: Also, you'd be much better of with Levenberg-Marquardt rather than Gauss Newton. Look up `nlsLM(...)` in the `minpack.lm` package. It has the came prototype as `nls(...)`.

Comment: I see the point in your first comment! Yes, the givendata has actually > 18 points (used 18 only for minimal example), but for each time point we have here 6 measurements as we look 6 categories of cells (those how divided themselves respectively 0,1,..5 times).

Comment: So do you want six models: givendata vs time for each category of cell?? It's not at all clear (to me) what you're trying to do here.

Comment: the measurment points (y_i, t_i) are given (whereas in this minimal example the y_i is only 3-dim vector (originally from R^6) and t_i fixed time point. I want (Not sure if the code, the way it is right now, expreses it) to apply the Gauss-Newton-method, so as to minimize the (double) sum of squared errors.

Comment: I assume your question refers to fitfunc, with which I created a sequence of population of cells, where each 3rd loop, the time "increases". In other words, first third elements of the build sequence represent the "modeled" population of cells, which got through cell division respectively 0,1 or 2 times. (as I wrote my first comment, I forgot that I reduced the dimension of the sequence "givendata", so in this minimal example we look only 3 categories of cell in each time point)